# Activerecord CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to count the number of items in my database within my card, but it's not working.

[image]

This is my home.html

Where my date-to is already included

```
     <div class="content">
         <div class="text">ITEMS</div>
         <div class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="<?= $active_properties; ?>" data-speed="1000" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
     </div>
```

And this is my home_model

```
     public function get_active_properties(){
        return $this->db->count_all('ci_properties');
    }
```

And my controller home

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user/home_model','home_model');
}

public function index(){        
    $lista = $this->home_model->listAll();
    $dados = array("ci_properties" => $lista);
    $dados['active_properties'] = $this->home_model->get_active_properties();
    $dados['title'] = 'Home';
    $dados['view'] = 'user/home/home';
        $this->load->view('layout', $dados);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this

```
<div class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="" data-speed="1000" data-fresh-interval="20"><?= $active_properties; ?></div>
```